# Why is Entity Framework creating a discriminator column for my View Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, inheritance

I've just read quite a few posts on `Table per Type`/TPT and the discriminator column, but, I'm not really any the wiser in my situation.

Taking an example: I have a MVC app that has a model called `Foo`. This has one property called `Bar` that is stored as a one to many elsewhere.

I am the only one using this app and I didn't want to spend a lot of time on it, so I just wanted the quickest way to add items to the list in `Bar`. Because of this, I made a new class called `FooViewModel` that is derived from `Foo`, and had a string property called `BarTemp`.

The basic idea is that I can type `111, 222 , 333,444` in to a standard text field and have the edit/create controllers clear whitespace and split to a list on the comma.

What I can't figure out is that the view model will never be written to EF, so, why is it creating the discriminator column.

It looked like when I tried to scaffold a migration, it event tried adding `BarTemp` to the DB.

I have since created a new type called the same, but instead of deriving, I just have `Foo` and `BarTemp` as properties in it which works as expected, but, I still don't get what happened and would like to learn more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because EntityFramework parses the hierarchy. Just because your current code doesn't ever save a `BarTemp`, there's nothing explicitly stopping you from writing:

```
context.Bars.Add(new BarTemp());
```

There's nothing EntityFramework can do to detect the above. So, it plays safe and assumes that if you inherit from an entity, your subclass will *also* be an entity. That's a correct assumption - and you shouldn't make view models inherit from the entity. Neither should they be properties. I'm really unsure *how* you've setup your current code, but the classes should be completely distinct. For example, it should look something like:

```
class BarTemp
{
    public string BarId { get; set; }
    public string Foos { get; set; }
}

class Bar
{
    public string BarId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}
class Foo
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Bar Bar { get; set; 
}
```

Your view model should know nothing about the entities, and the entities should know nothing about the view models. Your code accepting the input should do the work converting the view model to the entity. For example:

```
private void Update(BarTemp barTemp)
{
    var bar = context.Bars.GetById(barTemp.BarId);
    foreach (var foo in barTemp.Foos.Split(","))
    {
        var foo = context.Foos.GetById(foo);
        bar.Foos.Add(foo);
    }
    context.Save();
}
```

Don't take the above as an example of good code - it's extremely inefficient - but it should show you an example of where the conversions should take place, and how to keep the entities and view models separate.

Comment: I still think it is weird conceptually... I have a class, I define separately a dbset of that class... and I am deriving from the original class, not the entity framework object. I never ever thought about saving the view model directly and it just seems rather weird to me, but, at least I understand a bit more now, so, thanks!